# How to allow users upload photos with different dimensions?

Tags: swift

New to the Swift world.

I have implemented the function for user to upload an image using `UIImagePickerController`. However, I am a bit confused about the dimension of image to be uploaded.

People can upload images with different dimensions in Pinterest so in the main page, we see a beautiful Waterfall collection view (the size of cell determined by the height of an image).

The Pinterest App is super slow in China, let me use a similar App as an example. As you can see, the size of each cell in the Collection View is different.

[image]

The size of each cell is determined by the height of the image. For example:

```
extension MainViewController: PinterestLayoutDelegate {
  func collectionView(
      _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
      heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return photos[indexPath.item].image.size.height
  }
}
```

In order to achieve this view, the App has to allow user to upload images with different dimensions.

In my storyboard, I have created one Image view and one "upload image" button.

When the button is pressed, the following function will be called:

```
 func presentImagePickerController(with sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, from viewController: UIViewController) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        viewController.present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
    }
```

The content mode of Image View is set to be "scale to fit". However, the dimension of the image view is fixed.

If we look at the same App, when people upload an image, it asks people to select one of option from `original size`, `square` and `customized/crop`:

[image]

Does this mean I need to create different Image Views with different dimensions and let users pick the dimension they want?

Or in general, how to enable users upload images with different dimensions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question was voted down.. but can people at least explain why you think this question is useless to the community?

Comment: Because you need to follow SO guidelines: you have to say what you already tried, eventually provide your code and say why it works and why it does not; if you can’t even manage to write some code then you need to mention what you found online and where and say why it did not work for you.

Comment: Let me elaborate this question a bit

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share an image to apps use this code:

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [yourImage], applicationActivities: nil)
        activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        self.present(activity,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

when you call this, share view will present. easy
if you have any problem, let me know. fill free

Comment: Yep! Thanks.  I figured how to share an image, yet I am not sure how to allow people to upload photos with different dimensions.

Comment: @xdai1091i think you don't have limitations for image size. but you can change image size before sharing that.
your question is not clear for me.